# 3 phase line operating via 3 one phase relay

Tags: relay, three-phase

I want to operate a 3 phase 10Hp motor pump. I have a 3 phase electric line, but due to some requirements, I have to operate each line (A-B-C) in 3 phase using 1 phase relay separately.

My question is, can I operate each phase using single phase relay at same time (may be with fraction of delay because of relay are differ for each)?
Will this harm my pump?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your `some requirement`? Since it is very uncommon.

Comment: I have *never* heard of a case where you have to energize the phases separately on a 3ph motor -- that sounds like a recipe for a fried motor, even!

Comment: You could add a missing phase detector to protect the motor, but it would be better to use a proper motor starter.

Comment: Do you need to do this because you don't have a 3 Phase relay available?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. 3 phase relay is not available for 10hp motor pump to control @Tyler

Comment: I know It is unusual. As my application is to turn on/off pump automatically at some particular time, via sending signal from my controller and 3 phase relay is not available for thatl. I ask this question, after some research and not getting any proper solution.

Comment: @Rajvi I warn you: what you want to do is unsafe and contain lots of pitfalls and can lead to damaging your hardware as well as injuries. You can use your controller output to control the coil of external 3-phase contactor. That will be much better solution, than  using relay outputs for handling with large current (if you are talking about PLC), or placing high current circuitry and relays on PCB (if you are talking about microcontroller).

Answer (score 1):

It may harm only in case if something goes wrong: for example if coil in one of the relays is damaged or there is no contact with it, then your pump can be powered only with two phases which is no good. Another thing you may take into consideration is overcurrent on motor pump launch which can lead to contact "sticking", you can get into trouble when shutting down your device if two or three relays have their contacts stuck. These are the troubles, I have met with chinese PCB relays.

You better not use PCB relays: they are not intended for handling large overcurrent spikes, also motor back-EMF can cause arcing on it's contacts. If you have three industrial-grade single pole contactors, everything should be honky dory if you tie them properly. The probability of the failure is not that high at all.

Comment: Thanks. As I want to control pump via signal sending from my controller and make pump turn on/off automatic, I don't think I can use contactors.